# Algorithm behind longest increasing subsequence

Tags: dynamic-programming

I need a walkthrough example to understand following algorithm. It is taken from Algorithms by Dasgupta. Here is the algorithm they give to find the longest increasing subsequence.

```
 for j = 1, 2, . . . , n:
     L(j) = 1 + max{L(i) : (i, j) ∈ E}
 return maxj L(j)
```

and here is the graph:

[image]

I understand that L(j) represents the LIS ending at j; however, I don't understand the following: **max{L(i) : (i, j) ∈ E}**

A walkthrough example is highly appreciated to understand how this loop will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

E is most likely defined before this pseudocode, it is a set of pairs `i, j` such that `i < j` and `X_i < X_j`

It simply means length of LIS for all numbers left and smaller than the current one. Python code:

```
X = [5, 2, 8, 6, 3, 6, 9, 7]
L = []
for current_value in X:
    # the whole algorithm is in this line:
    # take the LIS of a smaller preceding number and increase by one
    L.append(1 + max((l for l, x in zip(L, X) if x<current_value), default=0))
result = L[-1]
```